# Trait or Class that requires an implicit in order to exist?

Tags: scala

So I find myself with code that has something like this:

```
trait Helper[T] { def canMakeA:T }

trait A

class Example extends A{
}

object Example {
  implicit val myHelper extends Helper[Example] 
}
```

The point of which is that I'll always need a Helper[A] object when something is working with trait A (it's extended classes). And this is simple enough to declare in a receiving function or class:

```
class Runner[T<:A:Helper] {   //T <: A and Helper[T] implicitly exists
... implicitly[Helper[T]] ...
}
```

However, I'm wondering if I can just bind trait A (and it's various descendant classes) to this requirement in the first place. Something like:

```
trait A:Helper {  //INCORRECT - EXAMPLE ONLY

}
class Runner[T<:A] {    //not necessary to use A:Helper, already implied as defined in A
    ... implicitly[Helper[T]] ...
    }
```

Is Scala somehow capable of this? Thanks!

OK so just to clarify, I'm simply stating that class A and Helper[A] must exist at all times because I need the implicit object to build objects of class A. Can you define class A in such a way that the implicit Helper[A] must exist..

I suppose this would work, but is there a more idiomatic way? Thank you

trait A[T<:A:Helper] {

}

class B extends A[B]{

}

object B{
  define implicit Helper here..
}

Comment: I am not clear on how your scenario is not solved by an implicit class or implicit conversion from `Example` to `Helper[Example]`.

Comment: What im trying to say is that class A (lets say holding data) is a separate thing from Helper[A] (which contains some static utility functions such as constructing A from a CSV file, for example). I can code these things perfectly fine in my first example .. but my question is can "A" be defined in a such a way that a Helper[A] object is assumed along side of anything working with the "A" class.. declaring A:Helper would be redundant for example. thanks

Comment: Another example where this would be useful is requiring that (in Play 2.1) implicit Reads or Writes exist for all classes extending a trait. I tried the suggestion you give in your clarification, but I get a compiler error: traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds ': ...' nor view bounds '<% ...' Also, in `trait A[T<:A:Helper]`, The second `A` needs a type parameter...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, that you always wish to have a helper available when working with `A` and not not sometimes (for which you have implicits as mentioned in the first example), then how about:

```
trait A extends Helper[A]{
   def canMakeA:A = //
}
```

This does exactly solve the purpose.

Comment: please see my update above, but thank you for taking the time.